# Why does the `HWaddress` field of my router as returned by `arp` not match the output of `ifconfig`?

Tags: ip, arp

I am a software engineer trying to learn about networking from [Ben Eater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNbdeyEI-nE&list=PLowKtXNTBypH19whXTVoG3oKSuOcw_XeW&index=10)'s video series.

By looking at my wifi connection info, I think I have learned that my router's IP address is `172.20.20.1`. (This is the value of the field **Default Route**).

When I run `arp`, I get this output.

```
$ arp 172.20.20.1
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask  Iface
172.20.20.1              ether   00:00:00:02:02:02   C           wlp1s0
```

But when I run `ifconfig`, I get (among other things) this output:

```
wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:94:67:af:28:2d  
          inet addr:172.20.20.20  Bcast:172.20.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Shouldn't the `inet` addresses match? Why is `HwAddress` equal to `00:00:00:02:02:02` while the other is `e0:94:67:af:28:2d`?

Is there a concept I am misunderstanding?

Comment: ARP stands for Address Resolution Protocol, and it is used to resolve layer-3 (e.g. IPv4) addresses to layer-2 (e.g. MAC) addresses so that layer-2 frames can be built for layer-3 packets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default gateway IP address is that of your uplink router, not your local address. Your local IP address appears to be 172.20.20.20 (`e0:94:67` indicating an Intel NIC). The local MAC address doesn't appear in the ARP table because nothing will ever be sent there.

ARP is used to send IP packets within local Ethernet frames, so entries in the ARP table will indicate other devices within your local network (the table is a cache, so only recently used devices are listed).

`ifconfig` shows you the configuration details of your local NICs.

The default gateway's MAC `00:00:00:02:02:02` appears not to be valid. The OUI `00:00:00` belongs to Xerox and has probably been out of use for decades. (Not a problem though, it just needs to be unique within your network.)

Comment: Ah, I see -- so to rephrase, the `arp` command is showing me info about my router, while `ifconfig` is showing me info about myself?

Comment: Pretty much so. The ARP table can hold entries for other, local systems as well, of course.